# css dropdown - gap wanted

Tags: css

My dropdown menu is now working with my css triangles (yesterdays problem), but now i would like a 2-3 px gap to the dropdown, but the moment i add that, i have the problem, that when you slide the mouse from the main nav point to the drop down, the drop down disapears (obviously as the mouse is no longer over the li link.)
So anyone got any good ideas, how i can have a gap, without the drop down dissapearing ?

http://keith464.fahrradhamburg.de/Lager/Metall-Behaelter/Stahlblech-Behaelter/Stapelbehaelter-aus-Stahlblech.html

Comment: Please add information about what HTML element you are talking about, pictures or IDs would be a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another container to hold your dropdown, witch will have transparent background and will be larger than your menu by 3px at the top, so you'll actually display that container too at your mouse hover, and nothing will disappear

LE: or you can show your dropdown by using javascrip and set a timeout to it, so it won't disappear that fast if your mouse is not over any `<li>`

Comment: another container div breaks everything.
and using javascript somewhat looses the point of a pure css menu

Comment: @JohnSmith how another div breaks everything? Can you be more specific?

Comment: er....actually no it doesn't if you put it in the right place...., although the css will need reworking.
but it doesn't help, padding just pushes everything down with no gap, margin gives you a gap but same problem as before

Comment: Try harder, you can now set a margin-top if you wish instead of a padding-top for your ul, It will work, but you'll have to try it for yourself

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to add this to your ul ul (drop down menu):

```
margin-top:-3px !important
```

The important tag ensures this margin takes precedence over any existing styles.